# Model Comparison with Regression

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, model-comparison, mediation

For a project I have to test a mediation model. I will do this with regression in R. The steps I take are the regular steps:

- Test if the IV has a relation with the DV (Regression)
- Test if the IV has a relation with the Mediator (Regression)
- Test if the IV + the mediator have a relation with the DV (Multiple Regression)
- Test if there is a mediation effect (Sobel)

My problem is that for the project I should not rely to much on p-values. So I want to do a model comparison. However, I'm a bit lost about what measures I should use for the model comparison (RMSE? AIC? etc?)

**I would like to know, which measures I should use in this model comparison and if there is a good example of how to pick them?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends in your objective with this model, you want to use it for prediction or to find the effect of one variable on other? Plus, different statistics are better for different scenarios in the same objective, for example: BIC penalizes model complexity more heavily, so if you have a sample with large variation, it might be in your interest to go extra steps to reduce your model and use BIC instead of AIC. If you say more about what you want i can make a more objective answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. First I would like to mention that I'm not sure about the variation in the data. I have to make a proposal for a study withouth seeing the dataset (of course I know what kind of variables are in there). Second I want to find out if there is a relationship between the IV and the DV (IV --> DV) and compare that proposed relationship with the relationship of the IV + Mediator on the DV (IV + Mediator --> DV). For that I want to do model comparison.

Comment: Well i don't know why you can't rely on p-values, but that would be my first suggestion. You can also run the model $DV \sim IV + Mediator$ and run a F-test with the null $H_0: B_{Mediator}=0$, which will tell if the inclusion of Mediator significantly changed the SSE. As for the statistics: Adjusted R², AIC, BIC, and several other all have the same ideia of penalizing model complexity and larger errors, and all in a very close way, so as you don't have much idea about your data it's hard to chose a 'better' one, my suggestion is do them all and compare results.

Comment: Sorry for the inclarities about p-value. I can rely on p-values but not on p values alone so I have to do model comparison. I will compare your suggestions. Thanks for your help.